# Select a row where a column has the most approximate value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to know the percentage of commission that the salesman has right based on the profit margin that the product was sold.

For that, I have the following table:

```
Margin    Commission
--------------------
15         9
30        10
60        11
70        12
80        13
90        15
```

Let's assume that the profit margin was 29. So I need a query that returns the second row (with margin 30, the most approximate).

How can I write a SQL query that returns this row?

Thanks

Comment: I solved my problem with the following query: SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable WHERE Margin >= 29 ORDER BY Margin ASC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a simple query using abs()

```
declare @m table(Margin int,    Comission int)
insert @m values (15, 9)
,(30, 10)
,(60, 11)
,(70, 12)
,(80, 13)
,(90, 15)

declare @target int; set @target=29

; with r as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by abs(Margin-@target)) closest
    from @m
    )
select * from r where closest=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply`:

```
select sp.*, c.commission
from salesperson sp outer apply
     (select top (1) c.*
      from commissions c
      where c.margin <= sp.margin
      order by c.margin desc
     ) c;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery for this problem. Most approximate >> use Min(ABS()) to get its.

```
select * 
from table 
where (select Min(ABS(table.Margin - "your profit") from table ))
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation also?

Comment: @nilambar : It's my first comment so it seem not fullfill, Thanks